# Access Json Object return from express js with angular html template

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angular, express

I am trying to access JSON from angular html template. But it is not returning results. Simply showing Object or error by modification of code.

**server.js**

```js
response.status(200).json(results.rows);
```

**product.component.ts**

```js
export class ProductsComponent implements OnInit {
  products = {};
  usersJson: any[]=[];

  constructor(private service: Service) {

   }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.service.getResult().subscribe((data: JSON)=>{
      console.log(data);
      this.products = data;
      this.usersJson = Array.of(data);
      console.log(this.products);
    }) 
  }
```

**data**

```json
data = [
 {product_id: 1, product_name:"Phone"},
 {product_id: 2, product_name:"laptop"}
]
```

**product.component.html**

```html
<p>{{ products}}</p>
<h1>Product</h1>
<p>{{ products[0].product_id}}</p>
<p>{{usersJson[0]}}</p>
<p>{{usersJson[0].product_id}}</p>
```

Comment: What is JSON type in your .subscribe method? I think you should change it to some interface, e.g. {product_id: number, product_name: string}. Also please check that: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6. If it doesn't help, could you show us result of console.log(data)? Also please show your service and getResult method.

Comment: what does your service method look like, `service.getResult()`?

Comment: `getResult():Observable <JSON>{
    return this.httpClient.get<JSON>(this.API);
  }`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **json pipe** and '.?' notation to ensure that will not be problems with undefined fields:

```
<p>{{ products | json }}</p>
<h1> Product </h1>
<p>{{ products[0] != null ? ( products[0]?.product_id | json ) : 'N/A' }}</p>
<p>{{ usersJson[0] != null ? ( usersJson[0] | json ) : 'N/A' }}</p>
<p>{{ usersJson[0]?.product_id }}</p>
```

NOTE: If product_id is a number/string and not an object, change

```
( products[0]?.product_id | json )
```

to

```
( products[0]?.product_id )  [just delete the json pipe in that line]
```

Comment: Last 3 lines are not working. This is my `getResult():Observable <JSON>{     return this.httpClient.get<JSON>(this.API);   }` service logic

Comment: Add to your question what is showing console.log(data) and what shows {{ products | json }} in the HTML, please.